# Snowflake SQL: Selecting the top 1% of IDs by Spend Amount partitioned by industry

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data table like the following (thousands of records) with spend associated to an ID that is bucketed in an industry TYPE.

Essentially, I want to return the only the top 1% of ID's by **Spend** (3rd column) and partitioned by **Type**

In the desired output below (2nd table), as you can see, I have queried the original data table and only returned the top 1% of IDs within each Type and showed the spend amount accordingly.

Summary: Goal is to slim down the original data table of thousands of records, to the top 1% for each each type (e.g. media, null, professional services etc.) by Spend amount.

Original Data Table:

```
ID      Type                    Spend
4412740 Media                   145545
3300640 Real Estate             141449
6781206 Professional Services   125378
4458933 Consumer Discretionary  122604
4684890 NULL                    113363
6781222 Professional Services   123
4458931 Consumer Discretionary  211
4684222 NULL                    4242 [...]
```

Desired output:

```
ID      Type                    Spend
4412740 Media                   10000000
3300640 Media                   9999998
6781206 Media                   9999997
4458933 Media                   9999996
4684890 Professional Services   99999
213124  Professional Services   99998
4343411 Professional Services   99997
468422  NULL                    88888
4343334 NULL                    88887
4684221 NULL                    88886 [...]
```

I attempted to do this with some SQL CTE's and functions but have trouble with getting the 1% based on Spend and partitioned by Type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `qualify`.  Here is a simple method using `ntile()`:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify ntile(100) over (partition by type order by spend desc) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! This makes great sense! 
Can you brefiley explain how the ntile(100) method works? I imagine this is taking the 1% of spend for each type?

Comment: `ntile()` is a window function that breaks the data into equal-sized (as much as possible) groups.  So, with 100 there are 100 equal-sized groups.  The first is the top 1%.

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down for me! Learned something new!!! And thats why this all equates to a 1 at the end